# Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: Integer Date.dayOfYear()

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to the salesforce and trying to execute the below code and see the error:

```
System.debug('Date :'+ Date.today());
System.debug('Date + 1 :'+Date.today().addDays(2));
System.debug('Add Months : '+Date.today().addMonths(3));
System.debug('Add Years : '+Date.today().addYears(5));

System.debug('Day Of year : '+Date.dayOfYear()+'');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Date.dayOfYear()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_dayOfYear) method needs to work on a instance of Date.

E.g.

```
System.debug('Current Day Of year : '+Date.today().dayOfYear());
```

Gives:

> Current Day Of year : 103

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place for Salesforce specific questions.